# How to sum with $\epsilon_{ijk}$?

Tags: tensor-calculus, vectors

How does one find the sum with $\epsilon_{ijk} $? For example,  $\sum\limits_{i,j,k=1}^3 \epsilon_{ijk} \frac{a_i b_j}{c_k} T_k$? Here $a_i, b_j$ and $c_k$ are scalars and $T_k$ is an operator.

Comment: If $a,\,b,\,c$ are scalars, why do they have indices on them?

Comment: The edit doesn't look correct to me. The condition for the sum to be zero is not $a_i b_j= b_j a_i$ (which is generally true) but rather $a_i b_j = a_j b_i$ (which is not generally true).

Comment: @KyleKanos Presumably "scalar" here means "scalar in the linear space on which $T$ acts," not "scalar in three=dimensional Euclidean space."

Comment: If  for all $i$, $a_i=a$ and $b_i=b$, where $a$ and $b$ are scalars (constants), then the sum is equal to 0.

Comment: What is the meaning of operator here? Is it quantum mechanics? Is it a matrix? Differential operator?

Comment: @Buzz OP erased the indication of scalars following your latter definition, but you can see it in the edit history.

Answer (score 3):

$\sum_{i,j,k}^3=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3$, now open each of those sums and use the properties of the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{1,2,3}=\epsilon_{3,1,2}=\epsilon_{2,3,1}=1$ (cyclic permutation), $\epsilon_{2,1,3}=\epsilon_{3,2,1}=\epsilon_{1,3,2}=-1$ (anti-cyclic) and any other combination of $i,j,k$ is 0. You pass from 27 to 6 values to check.

In order to provide a more specific answer you need to provide the properties of $a_i,b_j,c_k,T_k$.

Comment: Thanks, @Mauricio, it now seems that the sum should be zero irrespective of the properties of $a_i,b_j,c_k$ and $T_k$.

Comment: @seeker That could be the case if one of those if the products is symmetric with respect to two indices, without further information it is not possible to know. For example $\sum \epsilon_{i,jk}d_{i,j}=0$ if $d_{i,j}=d_{j,i}$.

Comment: Thanks @Mauricio, but  $a_i$  $b_j$   $c_k$ are scalars and $T_k$ is an operator that depends only on one index so where does the question of symmetry (under the interchange of indices) arise?

Comment: @seeker that is up to you to develop the context of that equation. More information is needed. For example if $a_i=b_i$ that could work.

Comment: @seeker To confirm: there are no generic requirements that the sum be zero if no specific constraints are imposed on $a$, $b$, $c$ or $T$.

Comment: @Mauricio, do you agree with my EDIT?

Comment: @seeker In the last line of your edit, it was not clear if the sum was 0. For example, the term that was proportional to $T_1$ could be 0 only if $a_3b_2=a_2b_3$ but in general this is not necessarily the case.